# How can i get previous page values?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have created user info page where user enters details,after filling the user info page,then  clicks submit button. Then it redirects to second page, In  second page there are 2 buttons such as previous & Next. When user clicks previous button it redirects to previus page but values are not visible.
so what is the necessary functionality to be implemented.

Comment: Naveen that's a very short description that only allows us to guess at the problem. It may help if you include pieces of the relevant code . All may depend on how that previous is implemented and how your browser is configured. That may not be related to anything you can solve with salesforce depending on your setup. Please consider updating the question with more information for us.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using one controller for both the pages, then you have to pass the parameter in redirect URL. Because as soon as form is submitted, view-state gets wiped off.

So after reaching second page, when user tries to go back to previous page, you should pass parameter in link (Record Id), and based on Id, you can have a query in controller and fill the rest of fields based on query results.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to implement a wizard where there are "next" and "previous" buttons on several pages is to use the same controller class for the various different pages. (This obviously only works if you are creating the pages as a set.) The [view state](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State) is then automatically transferred from page to page.

See the Force.com Cookbook article [Creating a Wizard with Visualforce Pages](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-wizard-with-visualforce-pages) for more detail.